# Wordpress show me 404 on some pictures

Tags: wordpress

I made a backup ok large website made with WordPress, and I get 404 in some pictures. I saw that on those picture that failed to load the resized version work well

Comment: Did you take a look at the console log?

Comment: ```172.17.0.1 - - [28/May/2020:19:26:50 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Los7deJunior-Datos-que-deberi%CC%81as-saber-sobre-la-Bundesliga-300x176.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 201286 "http://localhost:32000/star-wars-cambio-todo/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"```

Comment: You are trying to load your image from localhost

Comment: from a docker container